# Question Marks in PHP Prepared Statement not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get some locations out of my database within a range of 100 meters from a given latitude and longitude.

I've found a query on the Google website which allows you to do so, however when I remove the variables in the query and replace them with question marks as you are supposed to in a Prepared Statement, it doesn't work.

My query is as follows:

```
$getLocation = $db->prepare("
        SELECT
          id, title, lat, `long`, verified, (
            3959 * acos (
              cos ( radians(?) )
              * cos( radians( lat ) )
              * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) )
              + sin ( radians(?) )
              * sin( radians( lat ) )
            )
          ) AS distance
        FROM markers
        HAVING distance < 0.0621371192
        ORDER BY distance
        LIMIT 1;
    ");
    $getLocation->bind_param("sss", $newLatitude, $newLongitude, $newLatitude);
    $getLocation->execute();
    $getLocation->store_result();
    $getLocation->bind_result($locId, $locTitle, $locLat, $locLong, $locVerified, $locDist);

    if($getLocation->num_rows > 0) {
        while($getLocation->fetch()) {
            echo "yes";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "no :(";
    }
```

I'm not a Prepared Statements expert, so please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Are $newLatitude, $newLongitude, $newLatitude really strings (in which case why are you passing them to the Radians function, which expects a numeric argument); or are they numeric values, in which case why are you binding them as `s` for string and not `d` for double (float)

Comment: I've changed the "sss" to "ddd" but no difference.

The markup of $newLatitude and $newLongitude are like this: 82.124575

Comment: So they are doubles, not strings.

I've also tried the functions doubleval() and floatval() on the values of $newLatitude and $newLongitude but that doesn't change antyhing either.

Comment: Some particular knowledge on the nature of the phenomenon called "statement not working" will relieve us from necessity of guessing.

Comment: The error I'm getting is:


Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line 28.

Comment: Well that does narrow it down, it means that the `prepare()` call isn't returning a prepared statement, but is erroring.... what is `verified`? Is it a stored procedure on the database?

Comment: verified is a column in my table. Is verified like a reserved name or something like long in mySQL? I had to escape the long column with `long`

Oh now I see I have forgotten a comma after verified, so I've added that. But still no working statement.

I also made a mistake in the table name it was marker not markers. The error I get when I try this query within PHPMyAdmin is: 

#1054 - Unknown column 'lng' in 'field list'

Comment: Oh god, I was being dumb. I didn't pay too much attention to the example code and the database they were using. They had a column called 'lng' where mine was called 'long'. So I've changed that and now it is working.. ..atleast not giving any errors anymore! Thanks guys

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is an extra pair of eyes looking at things for you to spot them yourself

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. That's what I love about StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventually I fixed my problem by changing the query to this:

```
$getLocation = $db->prepare("
        SELECT
          id, title, lat, `long`, verified, (
            3959 * acos (
              cos ( radians(?) )
              * cos( radians( lat ) )
              * cos( radians( `long` ) - radians(?) )
              + sin ( radians(?) )
              * sin( radians( lat ) )
            )
          ) AS distance
        FROM marker
        HAVING distance < 0.0621371192
        ORDER BY distance
        LIMIT 1;
    ");
```

Now it is working fine.

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.